# How to make this function run only once even after I modify the content of the element is attached to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try couple of hours to make this script to run only one time.

```
<script>
  $(document).load(function (){
  "use strict";
            document.getElementById("portfolio-height").style.height = $(this).height() + "px";
    }); 
</script>
```

The problem is in that when I change div "#portfolio-height" content this script make new height value of the div. And I want to run only once when I load the document.

Comment: .load does not mean the code will ONLY run once the document is loaded. It means that it will run INFINITE times provided that the document has loaded first

Comment: Yes but i want to take height of the div when document is loaded